# Bash interpreter change arguments order

Tags: bash, arguments

I have bash script and try run command inside it

That's ok

```
echo ${something:="zip -r -q $TAG -P $PASS $LOCPATH"}
>zip -r -q evolution -P evolution ~/.gconf/apps/evolution
```

That's ok too

```
zip -r -q evolution -P evolution ~/.gconf/apps/evolution
```

But here order have been changed only when passed values and added strange . -i

```
zip -r -q $TAG -P $PASS $LOCPATH
>zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r -q -P evolution evolution . -i ~/.gconf/apps/evolution
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

BASH FAQ entry #50: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
something=(zip -r -q "$TAG" -P "$PASS" "$LOCPATH")
"${something[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `type zip`, seems it's aliased to something.

Maybe put the full path of `zip` to override this ,something like :

```
/usr/bin/zip
```

Comment: Sorry man. I have been edited question. Zip works ok if not passed $params.

Comment: Not aliased.type zip
> zip is hashed (/usr/bin/zip)